# Improving SQL query efficiency

Tags: sql-server

I have a query which calculates a distance, it works as expected however it can take a long time to query with lots of data points.

I have tried adding distribution=hash and it has had some impact but not significant amounts.

```
CREATE TABLE #POI_PINGS_ALL
        WITH
        (
            DISTRIBUTION=HASH([UUID])
        )
        AS
        SELECT 
                l.[PoiId]
            ,   v.[UUID]
            ,   [CreatedOn]
            ,   v.[Lat]
            ,   v.[Lon]
        FROM #LOCATION_PINGS_COUNCIL_DISTRIBUTED v

        INNER JOIN #POI_LOOKUP l
        ON l.[CouncilId] = v.[CouncilId]

        INNER JOIN #POI p
        ON p.[PoiId] = l.[PoiId]

        WHERE 
            dbo.fn_GetDist(v.[Lat], v.[Lon], p.[Lat], p.[Lon]) <= p.[Radius]
```

Is there a more efficient way to write this query ?

Comment: Latitude/longitude calculations can be a pain.  I don't think any Btree index could be used to speed up your query, but if SQL Server supports geospatial indices, you can look into that.

Comment: `fn_GetDist` is a scalar-valued function; using an inline table-valued function is at least one way of speeding things up by allowing the query to exploit parallelism. But per Tim, looking into `geography`/`geometry` and [spatial indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-indexes-overview) may give much better performance without even the need for custom functions.

Comment: Can you post the indexes you have on your temp tables? Have you properly indexed those temp tables? How many rows in each, on average?

Comment: @pmbAustin I don't currently have indexes on the temp table tables, would you recommend adding indexing all columns (v.[Lat], v.[Lon], p.[Lat], p.[Lon]) ?

Comment: At the very least, if you have lots of rows (more than several dozen) you should index the rows on the columns used in the JOINs, and add INCLUDE columns for all the other columns used in the SELECT and the WHERE (or just add a PK on the column used in the JOIN). That would help significantly if your temp tables are large.